# How to localize default validation messages without using a resource file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am developing an application using ASP.NET MVC 5. For the texts localization I am using a database instead of resource files.

In order to get the properly translated error messages for the various validation attributes (such as `Required`, `Range`, etc), I am using a custom metadata provider deriver from `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`, as explained [here](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/14/creating-your-own-modelmetadataprovider-to-handle-custom-attributes/). So far so good, everything works as expected.

The problem comes when I want to translate the default error messages such as "Field X must be a number". It seems that the ASP.NET MVC engine is not handling these errors through attributes so the cursom metadata provider is useless in the case.

[In this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/03/31/localizing-default-error-messages-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-form.aspx) there is an explanation on how to translate these messages by using resource files, basically you add these lines in the `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax`:

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources";
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources";
```

...but I can't imagine how can I apply this when using a database for the texts.

So my question is: how to translate the ASP.NET MVC default (non validation attribute based) error messages when the texts are not in standard resource files?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848397/dataannotation-with-custom-resourceprovider