# .NET Mvc Localization

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to extend the DisplayAttrubte Logic from Mvc.
The bad thing is since `DisplayAttribute` is a sealed class I'm not able to inherit. Therefore I inherit from `DisplayNameAttribute`.

```
public class TranslatedDisplayAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            var myVariableName = ???;
            return TranslationService.String( myVariableName  );
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to use this Attribute just like the DisplayAttribute.

```
public class MyDto {

    [TranslatedDisplay]
    public string myVariable { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to get the variables name, where the Attribute is assigned so that in the `TranslatedDisplayAttribute` implementaion the variable `myVariableName` is automatically set to the variables name (myVariable)? I dont'want to do something like this.

```
public class MyDto {

    [TranslatedDisplay( Name = "myVariable" )]
    public string myVariable { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

And I dont want to use the translation approach with Resx files. But @Romias thank you for your answer.

```
[Display(Name = "XXX_YourPropertyItem", ResourceType = typeof(YourResourceFile))]
public string YourProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are aware of this, and you want to do the translation in another way, but the built-in method is using another overload of the `Display` attribute, using Resource files.

```
[Display(Name = "XXX_YourPropertyItem", ResourceType = typeof(YourResourceFile))]
public string YourProperty { get; set; }
```

So, "XXX_YourPropertyItem" is the item in the resource file, and the "YourResourceFile" is the name of the ResourceFile class.

Comment: I don't use Resx files that is why I don't want to use this approach. My translated resources are stored in a SQL database.

Comment: May be your approach could be extend the Resource provider... to get the translation from database. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2466530/7720